# Loose class coupling and data access

Tags: c++, oop, loose-coupling

I am trying to implement a complicated class whose construction requires the specification of a condition that allows the constructor to determine when the object has been constructed. Consider, for instance:

```
class RigidBody
{
    private:
        std::vector<double> trajectory_;
        // Other stuff...
    public:
        RigidBody(std::unique_ptr<TerminateCondition>, std::vector<double> const &);
        // Other stuff...
};
```

Here is what the constructor might look like:

```
RigidBody::RigidBody(std::unique_ptr<TerminateCondition> condition, std::vector<double> const &p)
{
    int n = 0;
    while(!condition->Done( /* Signature */))
    { n++; 
      /* Do other stuff... */ 
      // such as, trajectory_.push_back(sin(n * dt));
    }
}
```

I imagine `TerminateCondition` to be an abstract class.

**Demand 1**: Access to `RigidBody` members

I would like `class TerminateConditionAtRest: public TerminateCondition` to be able to use `trajectory_`, so that I could terminate on conditions such as `std::abs(trajectory.back() - trajectory_[0]) < epsilon`. Would I need to force `Done(...)` to take a `vector const &` as an input argument and pass `trajectory_` to it?

**Demand 2**: Flexibility with signature of `Done(...)`

I might want `class TerminateConditionNumSteps: public TerminateCondition` to flag `Done` when `n > 1000` or something similar. Basically, I could use some flexibility with the `/* Signature */` in there.

How do I achieve such a setup, wherein `TerminateCondition->Done` can make use of as diverse a set of variables available in the scope of the `RigidBody` constructor, such as private members like `trajectory_` or locals like `n`?

I'm just looking for ultimate flexibility in modeling the loop termination condition. It doesn't seem like an abstract class allows one to be flexible with input argument signature. On the other hand, an abstract class seems like the only thing that would allow me to specify the condition at run-time.

Thanks.

Comment: Concerning 1: You could alternatively pass a factory object, that will create the correct  condition in the `RigidBody` c'tor from `this` ie. having full `RigidBody` access (the `public` that is).

Comment: Concerning 2: Using an abstract base condition basically says: "Whether we are done, will be determined based on the following signature". If you don't want that, maybe you need something like a trajectory factory, that automatically desides whether it is done.

Comment: And finally in general: It seems like you have an interface (`RigidBody`) whose construction you wan't to separate / modularize. Why not do exactly this? Precisely: Add class `RigidBodyConstructionInfo` based on which a `RigidBody` can be constructed. The `RigidBodyConstructionInfo` in turn can be built from some factory interface whose implementation used could depend on runtime stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just my thought. Maybe you wanna use something like that?:

```
class TrajectoryCreator
{
public:
   virtual vector<float> create(const vector<float>& path) = 0;
}
```

Then you can create specific trajectory you want:

```
RigidBody( TrajectoryCreator& t, const vector<float> &p)
  : trajectory_(t.create(p))
{}
```

Main idea of this solution is move logic of creation of trajectory in separate class